# basic question on triangular maps in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

While doing the book "Probem Solving Strategies by Arthur Engel" I found this question:

"Can you draw a triangular map inside a pentagon, so that each vertex has an even degree?"

I know what degree of a vertex means, however I am not understanding what a triangular map means here? Also how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can think of triangular map as of planar graph with all polygons that appear being topologically triangles (i.e. having 3 vertices and 3 edges).

This planar graph is not a triangular map because the face in the middle is quadrilateral. However, if you add diagonal to it, it becomes a triangular map.

[image]

Comment: Are you counting all the non overlapping polygons? And if we add the diagonal the quadrilateral will still exist right?

Comment: Yes, you are counting non-overlaping regions. As if the regions are countries and edges are borders between them. When you add diagonal, you split the quadrilateral country into two triangular ones.

Comment: When you draw one diagonal, it will intersect the two opposite sides of the quadrilateral in two points. Upon joining the two points on the sides of the quadrilateral to the two other vertices of the larger quadrilateral, we get triangles, is that how you are telling is the new diagram a triangular map?

Answer (score 0):

A triangular map is a special case of a Regular map : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_map_(graph_theory)